# What is the fastest appliance/utensil to cream butter and sugar with?

Tags: equipment, cake, sugar, butter

I have:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

but even with the whisk on the stand mixer, it seems to take for ages compared to when I was a kid and used a:

[image]

I'm using room temp butter and mix it for 10-20 seconds before starting to add the sugar. What's the preferred tool?

**Information requested by @Ward:**

Cake batter is what I'm creaming the butter and sugar for.

The 10-20 seconds I just do initially before adding the sugar to spread the butter around. Probably not needed. I could be going for up to 10 minutes after that with the sugar before I give up, unhappy with the fluffiness, concluding that I must have too high expectations. I also find the resulting cake too dense as well.

**Update**

Just tried using the paddle but at night when it's not so hot and had better results. I think using room temp butter before during the day saw the butter melt before it started to cream.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kenwood/Kitchen Aid with the paddle attachment.  Yes room temp butter.

Comment: I must admit I haven't tried the paddle. Will do.

Comment: Its all about the paddle. :)

Comment: As they say, I'd hate to beat up the cream without a paddle.

Answer (score 2):

I myself don't have a Kitchen Aid. I start with a spatula and switch to the whisk after a minute or three.

You didn't mention having a spatula, but I think you do.

Comment: I really don't think that is the fastest method...

Comment: It is if you don't have a Kitchen Aid :) It's faster than.... let's say a fork.

Comment: Faster than a chopstick.

Comment: Faster than a toothpick

Answer (score 1):

I've been using my:

[image: KitchenAid Pro 600 mixer]

extensively for creaming over the last couple days - buttercream icing (1 1/2 lbs of butter/shortening, 2lbs icing sugar) and a couple big batches of cake batter (1+lb butter, 1 1/2 lb sugar).

I guess one thing I do a bit differently is to beat the butter for longer before adding sugar, for at least a couple of minutes.  Then I add the sugar slowly and work up to medium speed, stopping a couple times to scrape the bowl.  I spent at least 10 minutes, more like 15 before I went on to add the dry and wet ingredients.

One of the nice things about the stand mixer is that you can leave it running for a while with minimal attention while you work on the next step.

Comment: The paddle you have there, is that more like my whisk attachment picture above or my paddle (Kenwood's 'K' paddle)?

Comment: Sorry, that's not what I used, that's just a pic I found on the Intenet of the same model and colour mixer that I have.

Answer (score 0):

If speed is the main requirement, you can't get any faster than a Magic Bullet.

Answer (score 0):

The Kitchen Aid mixer with the whisk attachment does a great job, the most important thing is room temp butter - not too soft though as it still needs some structure to get the volume. If you used caster sugar this could speed the process a little as well.